# tested hot swap, now drive is in predictive failure

Tags: hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

I have a DL360 G6 (yes I know).   I decided to test hot swap and replaced a drive with another one.  THe other one failed, so I put the previous working drive back in.  It's now in "predictive failure" mode for that bay.

Is there anything I can do to fix this?  Did hot swap damage the drive?

I am not panicking, there wasn't anything on these drives that was dramatically necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You have a failed drive and a failing drive. Replace both.

Storage media wears out relatively quickly, even when handled properly. And if these drives are the same vintage as the server they are aging.

Comment: Hmm, but it wasn't failing until I put it back in?  It was fine, I pulled it, put it back in, and it's marked as failed.   Are you sure that there isn't something about hot swapping that causes failure?

Comment: @Blaze There is nothing inherent in hot swapping that causes failure. If there were, nobody would hot swap and the functionality would not exist. Your drive was already near failure, and most likely power cycling it put it over the edge. It's also possible that someone exposed the drive to inappropriate physical handling while it was out of the server (e.g. dropping it, using it as a football, etc).